# Create a Map String -> Function in Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary

I would need to map strings to functions. I tried the following:

```
def a(a: Int,..) = ...
```

which represents a generic function with various arguments,

then

```
val m: Map[String, Funcs] = Map("a"-> a)
```

where

```
 type Funcs = (Any*) => Any
```

but it doesn't really work.. I would like to make maps of mixed functions with a string as key.

Comment: What do you mean by mixed functions? Do you mean functions with one argument of any type, or functions with any number of arguments?

Comment: functions of variable arguments of any type mapped to any return type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not easy. In fact, it's nearly impossible at runtime to do this. At compile time, there are several tricks you can use, all of them found in the library [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless). You don't have to use Shapeless as [Miles showed in a gist](https://gist.github.com/milessabin/aae285025a32fac0f5c1) wherein he explained:

```
trait Assoc[K] { type V ; val value: V }
def mkAssoc[V0](k: String, v: V0): Assoc[k.type] { type V = V0 } = new Assoc[k.type]{ type V = V0 }
```

and now at compile time you can match all the different things you need

```
implicit def fAssoc = mkAssoc("f", f)
implicit def gAssoc = mkAssoc("g", g)
```

and retrieve them as

```
def lookup(k: String)(implicit assoc: Assoc[k.type]): assoc.V = assoc.value
```

if you push these into a class like he's done with his HMap, you could do something along the lines of a Poly1:

```
abstract class FMapper{
  protected def mkAssoc[V0](k: String, v: V0): Assoc[k.type] { type V = V0 } = 
    new Assoc[k.type]{ type V = V0 }

  def apply(k: String)(implicit assoc: Assoc[k.type]): assoc.V = assoc.value
```

and create a class such as

```
class Mapped extends FMapper{
  implicit val f = mkAssoc("f", f)
  implicit val g = mkAssoc("g", g)
```

but as you can see, it starts to get ugly fast...